# Module for fedex shipping for drupal 7

Tags: 7, commerce

I am using Drupal Commerce version 7.

I came across requirement for `FEDEX shipping module`. I installed it but in it's requirements, **uc_quote** is missing. I didn't find this module for Drupal 7.

I searched for this but it is supported only in Drupal 6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uc_quote is a part of the main [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) module. You can find it in the directory structure of ubercart at `ubercart/shipping/uc_quote`. And it is obviously present for Drupal 7 (as part of [Ubercart 3.1](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart)).
For commerce shipping there is a [sandbox project](http://drupal.org/project/1265066/git-instructions), but I haven't tested it.